# Why do we have *daily* series of T-bill yields?

Tags: interest-rate, government-bonds, yield, treasury, federal-reserve

I understand that each week the US Treasury issues new T-bills at different maturities (1-month, 3-months, 1-year, etc). As far as I understand, this issuance happens every Tuesday. After the auction, agents trade these securities in the secondary market. However, for example, in the day following issuance the 1-month security issued on Tuesday is not a 1-month security anymore. It's a 29-day security. Similarly, the 3-month security issued a month ago is now a 2-month security.

The Federal Reserve publishes the H.15 report everyday: [see it here](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/). They list, every day, the secondary market rates for different maturities. I am puzzled by how they make this computation since, in any day that is not a Tuesday, there is no US Government security being issued. The 4-week security from two days ago cannot be traded as a 4-week security from the point of view of today and so on. I cannot find the documentation on how the Fed (or by that matter, Yahoo Finance) collects this data. Only once a week they should be able to observe rates on securities that really are 4-week securities, or 3-month ones, etc.

I understand how the "Constant Maturity Rates" are computed, but they are a different beast and are reported *alongside* the t-bill rates on the H.15 report. Those make a lot of sense to me since we see many points of the yield curve every day and we interpolate across them. Importantly, these points move in time. Since we do the interpolation, I can see why we can compute the Constant Maturity Rates for any maturity, and we can do it every day.

Since everyone uses this in practice, I am clearly missing something. Is there any reference where I can understand how the measurements are made? Are the t-bill rates also interpolations? What really do I see when I go to Bloomberg and check the rates for different maturities ([United States Rates & Bonds - Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates-bonds/government-bonds/us))? Are those rates for the last batch issued?

Comment: Bonds in general are priced-to-yield for their value as between issue and redemption.

Comment: @SSpring sorry, but I don't entirely see how that is related to the question itself.

Comment: Intermediate value of a bond can be price or yield as one sets the other. Oh, there is market demand, or valuation, for intermediately time positioned bonds.

Comment: @SSpring that is not the main point. I agree with you. But when Fed reports rates on "3-month T-Bills", what asset are talking about? Are these rates for the last issuance of 3-month bills?

Comment: A three-month bill with two months to expiration is no longer a three-month bill to an intermediate market. That's why I said "intermediately time positioned".

Comment: @SSpring I agree with you and I point that out on my question. So: what asset has an yield rate equal to the one Fed is reporting? It's easy to compute the yield given a price of any bond, but what bond exactly are they using? That is my question.

Comment: I added late notes to some of the previous comments. But the financial markets value Treasury securities after the auction valuation.